# applying css3 translate property

Tags: css

I applied a translate property to a link.
`translate-y(-50px);` on hover and it works fine.
but when I hover mouse on image it reverse its animation like when first time I hover on it it translate to y -50px but the problem is when I mouse off from it it again translate to y -50px;

here is my code

```css
.nav{
  background-color:red;
  padding:10px;
  font-size:20px;
  transition:0.5s all;
  margin-top:80px;
}
.nav:hover{
  transform:translatey(-50px);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <a href="#" class=nav>Home</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a parent it will fix the issue and apply translate style when you hover on parent

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
}
.nav {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.5s all;
  display:block;
}
.parent:hover .nav {
  transform: translatey(-50px);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <a href="#" class=nav>Home</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/mh44fne6/)

html

```
<div class="navContainer">
    <a href="#" class="nav">Home</a>
</div>
```

css

```
.navContainer {
    transition:0.5s all;
    display:inline-block;
}
.navContainer:hover .nav {
    transform:translatey(-50px);
}
.nav {
    display:block;
    transition:0.5s all;
    background-color:red;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when the element moves the cursor is no longer hovered over it and therefor the `:hover` pseudo-class does not apply. The simplest way to fix this is to separate the element that will move from the element that will be hovered over.

Try separating the elements into parent and child and applying the translate to the child when that parent has `:hover`. You'll also need to apply `display: block` to the child to ensure the parent element maintains its dimensions when the child moves.

```css
.nav{
  display: inline-block;
}
.nav > span{
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.5s all;
}
.nav:hover > span{
  transform: translatey(-50px);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class=nav><span>Home</span></a>
```